# Find time of execution of old query in Oracle

Tags: oracle, oracle-11g

I have a delete query which was run on a table in Oracle 11g Enterprise Edition about 2 months back. I need to find the exact time of when the query was executed.

I found the query in the `DBA_HIST_SQLTEXT` view. But I do not see any date/time field in the table to find the exact time of execution. Is there any way that this can be found out?

I also tried to extract the same from AWR report. But snapshots are available only till 1.5 months back.

Comment: Logminer is probably your only option if the relevant data has aged out of the `DBA_HIST` tables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The typical retention period for an AWR report is 45 days. So unless, this period has been modified to 60 days (2 months) or more in your DB, the `DBA_HIST*` views will not have the information you are looking for. 
You can verify the retention period by querying the `DBA_HIST_WR_CONTROL` view.
In case the retention period has not been modified you can query the `DBA_HIST_ACTIVE_SESS_HISTORY` view and get SQL_EXEC_START time for the SQL_ID for a given period.

Comment: I checked the DBA_HIST_WR_CONTROL view. The retention for the said environment is set to 8 days. So is there any way to extract the timestamp of the query before that?

Comment: No don't think there is any other way through the database queries.

Comment: As mentioned by @Phil, in the comment you can use Logminer, but even that might not have data from so long back

Comment: @vishad The sql_exec_start will tell you when it was executed but not when its finished,

Answer (score 0):

It means you have the `SQL_ID` of the SQL statement and now you want to know when it was executed.

You can use the following query where you can supply the `SQL_ID` of the SQL query that you have in `DBA_HIST_SQLTEXT`.

```
SQL> SELECT timstamp FROM dba_hist_sql_plan WHERE sql_id='your sql_id';
```

Comment: Thanks JSapkota . But the query returns no result. How can it be that the DBA_HIST_SQLTEXT view contains the query but DBA_HIST_SQL_PLAN doesn't?

Comment: Oracle may have captured the SQL, but not the plan, that is why. if you need it to be captured, make it is colored sql (there is a procedure in dbms_workload_repository, and it is documented in the manuals too).